# Picking out terms according to proportionality in expressions

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I am trying to figure out how to pick terms proportional to $x$ (or any other expression).

I have the following problem:

I want to pick out $(1+2y) x$ from a polynomial of the form $(1+2y)x + e^xx + y^2$ (i.e., terms proportional to $x$).

I tried the command `Coefficient`, i.e. `Coefficient[(1+2y)x + e^x x + y^2,x] x`, but the output is $((1+2y)+e^x)x$. So the expression has $e^x$ in it and it is not what I am looking for.

**Is there a way to pick out only the terms linear wrt $x$ from the polynomial above? I.e. constant (for x) coefficients of $x^1$**

Thanks a lot.

Ps. I am only using the above polynomial as an example. In a real situation I'd expect to see polynomials with many special functions.

Comment: what does `terms proportional to x` mean?  In what sense is  `(1+2 y)` proportional to `x`

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the x term accidentally since that was what `Coefficient` was returning. I've edited the question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Perhaps `Cases[Expand@expr, Longest[a_.] x /; FreeQ[a, x] :> a]` works.

Comment: You mean the constant (for $x$) coefficients of $x^1$?

Comment: @march That seems to work! Thanks a lot! Feel free to post as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
prop[exp_] := 
 Module[{c = Coefficient[exp, x]}, 
  c =!= 0 && Cases[c, x, Infinity] == {}]
Select[ List @@ ((1 + 2 y) x + e^x x + y^2) , prop ]
```

> {x (1 + 2 y)}

note this only finds terms in the form given..

```
Select[ List @@ ((1 + 2 y + Sin[x]) x + e^x x + y^2) , prop ]
```

> {}

Comment: I see; thanks. However, I was looking for something a bit more general; it seems like March in comments section was giving the more general case. However, for a particular case this is very helpful, so thanks.